# svg animate tag changing

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg

I am trying to make a rectangule in svg move down and them,when you tap it,to go to the right but it seems that it doesn't work.The console doesn't show any error.

```
 Here is a JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/troosfx8/
```

Update:Thanks for the answers.But now I want to know how can I make the second animation begin if a variable is 5 for example.Is there any way I can make a svg animation begin based on a condition?

Comment: "Is there any way I can make a svg animation begin based on a condition?" You should ask another question for this rather than hope for new answers on this one. After all it *is* a different question.

Comment: I wanted to ask another question but I can't for 2 days...again. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much simpler solution than how you are attempting to do it above.

All you need to do is add another `<animate>` element that begins on a click.

```html
<svg width="360" height="400"
     style="border:#9999ff dotted 7px; border-radius:12px;" >
    <rect id="Rect" x="70" y="70" width="50" height="50"
          style="stroke:yellow; stroke-width:5px; fill:orange;">
        <animate id="pos" attributeName="y" from="70" to="140" dur="1s"
                 repeatCount="none" fill="freeze"/>
        <animate id="pos" attributeName="x" from="70" to="140" dur="1s"
                 repeatCount="none" fill="freeze" begin="click"/>
    </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you a loooot,Paul LeBeau!Thank you sooo much.